# SQL select statement issue

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

I'm facing a SQL SELECT problem:

There is a question, this question has an anwser, and this answer has a next question, and so on...
This is my query:

```
SELECT Q.question, A.answer, A.nextQuestion as 'next question' from answers A join questions Q on A.nextQuestion = V.questionId 
order by Q.question;
```

This is the output of the above query:

```
Question 1 | Answer 1 | 2
Question 1 | Answer 2 | 2
Question 2 | Answer 1 | 1
Question 2 | Answer 2 | 1
```

**So right now the 'next question' is a number... But I'd like to resolve that number to the next question text (Q.question)...
How can I achieve this?**

I want something like this:

```
Question 1 | Answer 1 | Question 2
Question 1 | Answer 2 | Question 2
Question 2 | Answer 1 | Question 1
Question 2 | Answer 2 | Question 1
```

Thanks in advance!!

**I'm working with MySQL.**

This is my table structure:

Table "Questions"

```
+------------------+
| Field            |
+------------------+
| questionId       |
| question         |
+------------------+
```

Table "Answers"

```
+------------------+
| Field            |
+------------------+
| answerId         |
| answer           |
| nextQuestion     |
+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data structure is missing a link from a question to answer.

So, I'm going to postulate the `answers` has a field `QuestionId` as well as `NextQuestionId`.  This is one way that you get the link you need.  If you don't have such a link, then you need to think some more about your data structure.

With such a field, a second join to `questions` gets what you need:

```
SELECT Q.question, A.answer, nextq.Question as 'next question'
from questions Q
     answers A join
     on A.QuestionId = q.questionId join
     questions nextq
     on A.NextQuestionId = nextq.QuestionId
order by Q.question;
```